# Regex keyword matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to implement a regex matching function in javascript that matches one or more keywords in a text. Each keywords has to be found in any order. Keywords are entered by the user.

Here's where i am at:

```
\b(smart.*\bwork.*|work.*\bsmart.*)
```

- matches `"trying to work smarter"`
- but not `"trying to work" or "trying to be smart"`

The problem with this approach is i have to create different ordered permutations (something like that anyway) of the keyword set.

So the questions are:

1. If there a simple RegEx-only way? (I.e `"\b(smart.*|work.*)<magic:all,anyorder>"` what will make sure all keywords are found, and in any order)
2. If not - can you suggest a javascript implementation of array permutations (so that from `[1,2,3]` it generates `[[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1]]`)

**UPDATE**

This is intended to be used for searching a set of strings (10-50 strings) on the client side (in browser).

Comment: I would not recommend regex when it comes to "these keywords in any order with interlaced acceptables".  I would recommend `indexOf()` on each keyword; it would cost a lot less than the potentially complex regex.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do. This isn't some spam randomizer is it?

Comment: Your second option sounds like a performance nightmare if you're going to use it to generate a bunch of RegExs and test them all.

Comment: @BeemerGuy Or even a sequence of separate regexes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My friend Juan's answer will work pretty well unless the user is looking for small words that may appear in larger words. In that case you'll need to fall back to regular expressions. You can use a hybrid approach that only uses the RE when the string is found. Something like:

```
String.prototype.containsAll = function(){
    for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {

        if (this.indexOf( arguments[i] ) > -1 ) {
            // test with regular expressions
            var re = new RegExp('\\b' + escapeRe(arguments[i]) + '\\b')  
            if (!re.test(this)) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;

    function escapeRe(re) {
        return re.replace(/[$.*+?()\[\]\\^]/g, function(chr) {
            return '\\' + chr;
        });
    }
}
```

Never tested, especially not the escapeRe bit.

Comment: Not bad!  I tested it and it does work, but only if every search word starts and ends with a word character.  You might want to replace the leading `\\b` with `(?:\\s|^)` and the trailing one with `(?:\\s|$)`.  But the OP only seems to care about the leading boundary.  Here's a demo based on that assumption: http://ideone.com/fZFzW

Answer (score 1):

Just because BeemerGuy didn't post it as an answer. But cred goes to him. There's not a RegEx that can do what you want, it is much simpler to create a method that uses indexOf. My performance tests indicate that you should always prefer indexOf over a RegEx if possible.

```
function containsAll(searchString /*, word, word,...*/) {
  for (var i=1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (searchString.indexOf( arguments[i] ) == -1 ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

or if you don't mind modifying String.prototype

```
String.prototype.containsAll = function(){
  for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (this.indexOf( arguments[i] ) == -1 ) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```